# Javascript Array push working randomly or interfering in post data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this function which is working correctly:

```
extractDataFromClusters(dataSource) {
let datas = [];
dataSource.clusters.map(cluster => {
  datas.push(<Text>SEPARATOR</Text>);
  cluster.map(data =>
    datas.push(
      <View style={styles.slide1}>
        <Text>{data}</Text>
      </View>,
    ),
  );
  datas.push(<Text>SEPARATOR</Text>);
});
return datas;
}
```

but when I replace the value in the push to the right tag values i would like to print:

```
  extractDataFromClusters(dataSource) {
    let datas = [];
    dataSource.clusters.map(cluster => {
      datas.push(<Swiper
            style={styles.wrapper}
            height={200}
            horizontal={true}
            autoplay>);
      cluster.map(data =>
        datas.push(
          <View style={styles.slide1}>
            <Text>{data}</Text>
          </View>,
        ),
      );
      datas.push(</Swiper>);
    });
    return datas;
  }
```

Then i got next error: "Reference Error: Can't find variable: data" . How is this possible?
How is it possible that just changing the push before the map function it crashes the funcion?
I did not touch that part of the code.

Doe anyone has any hint here? What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove trailing comma after `push` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's now how JSX works. :-) Pushing the beginning of a JSX tag (`<Swiper ...>`) in an array and then pushing the end of it (`</Swiper>`) later is like pushing half of a function call (`foo(`) and then pushing the other half later (`);`) (In fact, JSX tags are turned into function calls; [details here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html).) You're not building an HTML string. JSX is programming syntax, not textual notation.

Instead, complete the JSX tag, and use `{}` within it to provide contents for it:

```
extractDataFromClusters(dataSource) {
  return dataSource.clusters.map(cluster => (
    <Swiper
        style={styles.wrapper}
        height={200}
        horizontal={true}
        autoplay>
      {cluster.map(data => (
          <View style={styles.slide1}>
            <Text>{data}</Text>
          </View>,
        )
      )}
    </Swiper>
  ));
}
```

---

Side note: Someone, somewhere, is teaching `map` incorrectly and I'm afraid you've been exposed to the incorrect information. `map` is never the right tool to use if you aren't doing **both** of these two things:

1. Returning a value from the callback function that you want to use later.
2. Using the array that `map` returns.

In several places in your code, you're not doing either of those things.

If you just want to loop through an array, use `for-of`:

```
for (const entry of theArray) {
    // ...
}
```

or `forEach`:

```
theArray.forEach(entry => {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: *(Doh! I missed one. If you see `datas.push` in the above, hit refresh and it'll magically disappear.)*